# I have Code for adaptive payment for paypal but it shows blank

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I have tried to integrate the paypal Adaptive payment to pay multiple users. and this try to done in Codeigniter framework.
i have code for it runs without showing any error but it is not redirecting to paypal payment.

I have add all the headers and curl methods for it but it not working at all

Paypal header is constructor

```
$this->headers = array(
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".API_USER,
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".API_PASS,
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".API_SIG,
            "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
            "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
            "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ".APP_ID
        );
```

```
function _paypalSend($data, $call){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl.$call);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);

        return json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);

    }
```

$response = $this->_paypalSend($createPacket,"Pay");

Comment: Try using `echo curl_error($ch);` to print any errors. Use it after `curl_exec` but before `return`.

Comment: Are you sure that you shouldn't be setting the `Content-Type` since you are sending a raw JSON payload?

Comment: Have you tried using the [official SDK](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php)?

Comment: Hello KFoobar i have try for your suggestion but still this code get black response resther to redirect payment option.